# how to use each for loop in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing sms sending at time multiple number and I'm using each for loop. When I call `sendSms` method in for loop it shows change type of `Number` to `String`. I've checked every number in `if` condition whether number length is greater than one then send the sms. Here is my code.

```
btnSendSms=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1_SendSms);
btnSendSms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String message="Hi HElooo";
        String[] number={strCellNo1,strCellNo2,strCellNo3,strCellNo4,strCellNo5};
        Log.e("String Array","->"+number);
        for(int i=0 ; i<number.length ; i++) {
            if(i==0) {
                sendSMS(number, stringMessage);
            }
        }
    }
});

public void sendSMS(String number, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    // SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);  
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    unregisterReceiver(sendBroadCastReciever);
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadCastReciever);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Why do you need a loop if you only send when i==0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mention the index of the `String` to be used from the `number` array.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<number.length ; i++){
    if(i==0){
        sendSMS(number[i], stringMessage); // mentioned the index here.
    }
}
```

The `for` loop is not required, unless you have an alternate flow(a possible `else` statement within the `for`).

Comment: no looping needed though! sendSMS(number[0], stringMessage); is enough.

Comment: Well that's on the logic of the OP. May be in the case mentioned, the loop ain't required! Nevertheless, that's out of the scope for this question!

Comment: @LazyNinja you're a ninja for quickly spotting a design flaw in OP's code (and duplicated in the answer) but too lazy to post it as part of your answer :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, hahaha LOL! I thought this answer would suffice.